# How to make Turtle's screen.listen() not listen when it is executing the function?

Tags: python, python-turtle

In this sample code:

```
def some_function():
    //do something
   
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(some_function, "space")
```

how to make `screen.listen()` not execute again until `some_function` is done executing? I tried doing this:

```
is_executing = False

def some_function():
    is_executing = True
    //do something
    is_executing = False
    
if not is_executing:
    screen.listen()
    screen.onkey(some_function, "space")
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turtle doesn't allow you to (intentionally) turn off `screen.listen()`.  But what I do in the situation you describe is the following:

```
def some_function():
    screen.onkey(None, 'space')
    # do something
    screen.onkey(some_function, 'space')
    
screen.onkey(some_function, 'space')
screen.listen()
```

The idea is that pressing space while `some_function()` executes will have no effect until `some_function()` finishes.  This can prevent a faux recursion that occurs when you (re)invoke an event handler while it's executing, and other problems.

You can find yourself unintentionally turning off `screen.listen()` when invoking turtle's `textinput()` and `numinput()` methods as they transfer listener status to the popup input windows.